# How do I call a function with params (x: A*)(y: A*)?

Tags: scala

Suppose I have a function that looks like this:

```
def foo(x: Int*)(y: Int*): Int = ???
```

How can I pass `Array`s of `x` and `y` to `foo`?

```
val x = Array(4,6,3,7)

val y = Array(3,4,6,3)

foo(x, y) // Error:Type mismatch
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `:_*` to tell the compiler to unpack the sequence to match the expected varargs input.  Also, since `foo` is declared using two parameter lists, calling the function has to match:

```
foo(x: _*)(y: _*)
```